# mouse functions api for windows

Tags: c#, winapi, kinect

im working on a proggram that i wanto set the position of my joints in kinect to mouse cursor.  i dont know the api that work with mouse  and its functions and which namespace i have to add.
for example some function to set the position to mouse pointer  and some function for right click and left click and double click. for example i want  "if my hand joint is upper my left joint mouse be clicked.   i can work with kinect sdk but i dint know about win api about it.
thanks for helping .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the position :

```
[DllImport("user32")]
public static extern int SetCursorPos(int x, int y);
```

For the mouse click :

```
[DllImport("user32")]
public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
public const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
public const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

public void MouseClick(int x, int y)
{
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
}
```

I think the code is pretty clear and simple, have fun ^^

Comment: what about keyboard api? can anyone tell me which api simulates keyboard functions?

Comment: Use this one : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.keyboard.sendkeys.aspx and don't forget to mark this as an answer :)